# The best way to specify http request id in all logs during processing this request

Tags: c++, algorithm, architecture

There is an http server that accepts tcp connections in one thread, then the parsed request is pushed into the thread pool. When there are many such requests, there is almost no sense in the logs, because it is not clear which request the entry in the log refers to. I want to issue an id to each request in a thread that accepts a connection and parses, and precede each log with such an id. The question is how best to do it? It is possible to pass a string with this id as an additional parameter to each function that is called in the threadpool worker, but it looks very clumsy. Any ideas how to solve this problem more gracefully?[image] I tried to depict this in an activity diagram. Here, through API, the db service does not receive information about the http request. Therefore, there is no information about his id. I can add an argument to the API of DB service, but this causes strong coupling and the API of DB service will look overloaded

Comment: At the first glance, don't log anything in `db_service`. Let `get_some_archive_info` return the db message, and log it in the `worker`.

Comment: yes, but I want to log with an idso that it would be easier to search for information on this request in logs and find the problem

Comment: Precisely. `worker` knows the id.

Comment: yes, but that's not enough. The problem is reproduced in the database server when a specific http request is received. I know what request it is, but I don't know what logs from the database service are related to the processing of this http request

Answer (score 0):

You can more loosely couple the DB service through simple naming of the parameter, call it trace_log or something, and generate it if it isn't passed in.  That way it's the responsibility of the calling function to know what to pass down.

Comment: yes this is how i do it now. I called this argument logging_entity. Super abstract name. It's work, but maybe someone will come up with a better solution